# Different dependency implementation in gradle depends on different android version

Tags: android, gradle

I have 2 libs imported to my project:

```
implementation fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')

libs/a.jar
libs/b.jar
```

Both libs have same classes inside as well as some different classes.

I need to implement needed lib depends on android version.
In example for `Android.P` I need lib `a.jar` and for `Android O` need `b.jar`

Currently I receive next issue when compile :

```
Execution failed for task ':app:transformDexArchiveWithExternalLibsDexMergerForEngProductionRelease'.
> com.android.builder.dexing.DexArchiveMergerException: Error while merging dex archives:
```

Thank you in advance for support.

Comment: The `gradle.build` file is a Groovy script. You can use conditionals as necessary.

Comment: @Henry but what kind of condition can be set in if statement?  Since one app may be installed on both Android versions. I need to find some "runtime implementation" mechanism I think